# Flask app user authetication using OneLogin

Tags: python, flask, flask-login, onelogin

I am working on a Flask webapp that requires user authentication.  Currently, username and passwords are stored in the database and the server side script checks the database and authenticate the user.  I am trying to change this to OneLogin authentication that this company is using.  I have no idea now how to get this task done.
How should I approach this?  Where should I get the info?

Thanks!!

Comment: First you should not store passwords! Never!

Comment: I do not store the password in the DB.  It was misleading statement.  Sorry about that.  I am just trying to migrate to Onelogin authentication from what I have now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What does your existing code look like? If it looks at all similar to the "normal" way to protect views (http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/patterns/viewdecorators/), it should be easy to adapt to using the library linked to by the company's developer documentation.
https://github.com/onelogin/onelogin-python-sdk

Comment: Great first post Terrel!  I especially appreciate the fact that you liked directly to the relevant references.

Comment: thank you very much for the information.  this will keep me busy for now!!!